# Import users to Mybb database from another mysql table of users

Tags: php, mysql, mybb

I have a website with a login/password section. it has approximatively 500 users. I've created the login and the password for all of them in a mysql table let's call it "users".

Now i've just installed a Mybb forum, which has its own mysql database (mybb_users).
I dont want people to register by themeselves, i just want them to use the previous login/password they were using on my regular website.

My questions are:

1)Can i import users from a csv file in the mybb application?
2)the database structure in mybb_users is: username     password    salt    loginkey

it is different in my "users" table which have only login and password (in cleartext)

How can i convert the password and create the login key to be usable in the mybb.

I cannot afford to create the 500 users manually.
I hope i was clear.

Thanks for your help

Comment: if the tables are on the same db you can make with " insert into table2 (user,pass) select user,pass from table 1 "

Comment: @RafaelShkembi Shkembi In the mybb admin interface, i can add manually a user. When i do so, it encrypt automatically the password by choosing salt and use also a login key

Comment: the tables are on the same database?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi no they're not, but i can export one table and import it to the other db

Comment: Yes you can upload them. You can read this [example](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/) it will help you.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi how do i manage with the loginkey and the salt filed, i don't have that in my users table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is different in my "users" table which have only login and password
>   (**in cleartext**)

**A solution that would work because your initial stored passwords are not encrypted at all:**

Reminder of your context:

- One custom kind of `MyUserLogin` table.
- MyBB's login table. Let's called it `MyBBLogin`.
- `MyUserLogin`'s passwords **are not encrypted at all**.
- `MyBBLogin`'s passwords are encrypted with MD5 + Salt.

A simple solution, aside from the CSV one, would be to create this kind of php script:

1. Select all users from `MyUserLogin` table.
2. For each returned user's password (`$password_cleartext`), apply this function:

   ```
   function generate_salt() {
       return random_str(8);  //picked from MyBB's source code
   }

   $passwordToStoreInMyBB = md5(md5($salt).md5($password_cleartext));
   ```
3. Then you just have to make an insert query to populate `MyBBLogin`'s fields, involving the newly encrypted password (`$passwordToStoreInMyBB`) **and** the salt key (`$salt`).

Note that `LoginKey` field is just a key generated at log in time by MyBB in order to prevent some kinds of CSRF attack, especially during the logout mechanism.
You don't have to populate it yourself.
More info about the essence of this key [here](http://community.mybb.com/post-846208.html) .